# Unable to change the view size in XIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make the view controller as size as 300x400, i have done following things,

- Open the XIB and go to the Size inspector
- Changed the width and height properties to 250 and 300
- Saved the file and closed interface builder

But its Not working ??

Comment: XIBs will not be recompiled some times. Just clean (Cmd + Shift + K) and run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on XIB 
Choose open As
chose source code
and change width and height ..

Answer (score 2):

Just double check with your code whether anywhere frame assign programmatically. If NO, just do following step.

```
1) Clean and build -> Run. If not work, go to second step.
2) Delete app on simulator and run again.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiii @Gautam, this can be possible, you can do the following things,

1. Clean your project because sometimes it will not recompiled. Run it again. If this not work then you can use 2nd way
2. Open the source code of `filename.xib` by using right clicking that xib and perform change to height and width.

Hope this will work for you...

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

First of all its important to know that how you are checking size is changed or not.

If you are doing addSubview of this resized xib into other view controller than you feel the change in xib. But in case you are using Push view controller than you will not feel the change. Because view controller will show over the window so you can not  change the window size.

Note :
If you want to show the resized view as an subview in any other page than you need to take subview in that view & make add subview of the current view.